# How could I create a graphic with nodes that contain links?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to use HTML, CSS, and JavaScript to create a menu that looks like so:

[image]

Each Chapter has a little "node" to the left of it that when clicked would bring the user to that chapter's dedicated web page. Is this something that could be done using canvas elements in HTML?

Comment: no need to use canvas for that, you could use before and after elements to make the circle and the line, all that on links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create the images for the bullets and then use the list-style-image property when styling list. You can then use JavaScript to keep track of the state. Assign the appropriate image based on what the user has clicked.

If you need a sample of the code to get this working let me see how far you get then I can add pointers.

[CSS list-style-image](https://www.w3schools.com/)